# Unable to set Outlook email UnRead property to false via MAPI with Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook, mapi

I don't appear to be able to write changes to Outlook via MAPI, the **.UnRead** variable is being set correctly to false within the script if you **Write-Output** it, but the variables don't appear to manipulate the actual .PST file. The **select** produces the correct emails, so read access to the .PST is fine.

Here is the code I am using to retrieve a list of unread emails from a PST folder, and set one of them to read:

```
$Outlook = new-object -comobject "Outlook.Application";
$Mapi = $Outlook.getnamespace("mapi");
$Pst = $Mapi.Folders.Item("Personal Folders")
$Folder = $Pst.Folders.Item("Test")
$Emails = $Folder.Items | Select UnRead, SenderEmailAddress, Subject, ReceivedTime, Body | Where {$_.Unread -eq "True"}

$Emails[1].UnRead = $false
```

Most examples I have seen say to place the variable in brackets, e.g.

```
$($Emails)[1].UnRead = $false
```

But this has made no difference for me.

Interestingly I get a 'method not found' error when I try to use the **.delete()** as well, hence I think I must be missing something.

Many thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: I think after `Select` everything is "read-only", if you remove it, does it work ? Or try `$Folder.Items[0].UnRead = $false`

Comment: Many thanks, I wasn't aware of that.  I have just tried `$Folder.Items[1].UnRead = $false` with the same result I'm afraid, or lack of!  `$Folder.Items[0].UnRead = $false` errors as there is no email in 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call MailItem.Save.

Do not loop through all items in a folder, use Items.Find/FindNext or Items.Restrict.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little ?

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, **items.Find()** allowed me to mark the email as read.  e.g. `$filter = "[UnRead] = True"
$UrEmails = $Folder.Items.Restrict($filter)`.  However **items.FindNext** and **items.Restrict()** return nothing, so I'm going to have to work on that for efficiently returning all the unread mails in a folder for processing and marking as read.

Comment: You need to make sure you call Find and FindNext on the same instance of the Items object instead of calling MAPIFolder.Items.Find and MAPIFolder.Items.FindNext

Answer (score 0):

You've change property of your own object, but not on mail server

Comment: Certainly seems that way, @sodawillow must be right about **select** returning a read-only copy of the mail items.

Comment: This has been flagged as low quality because its short. Add some detail to this answer to improve it and have it be the accepted answer.