# Powershell Set Unread flag for Outlook Desktop emails

Tags: powershell, outlook, office-automation

I am trying to read emails from a folder in Outlook Desktop using powershell, and I can do that with the code below.

**But is there any way by which I could also set the Unread property to $False for those emails
directly in outlook ?**   ( not in the objects stored in variables )

Browsing the website I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34161683/13568461 which says to use MailItem.Save but I cant figure it out how to update my code to make use of that.

Much appreciated if anyone can help with that piece of code. Thank you in advance

```
 Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
 $Outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application
 $namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
 $Folder_AI =   $namespace.Folders.Item('user@domain').Folders.Item('AI-ServiceDesk-Servers')
 
     $Count_ItemsUnread = $Folder_AI.UnReadItemCount
     
     $All_Folder_Items = $Folder_AI.Items | Select-Object -Property UnRead, Body
 
 
     $All_Folder_Items | ForEach-Object {
 
         $Email_Status = $PSItem.Unread
         $Email_Body = $PSItem.Body
 
         $Email_Status
 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

> But is there any way by which I could also set the Unread property to $False for those emails directly in outlook ? ( not in the objects stored in variables )

No, you need to get an item to set up a property. The `Save` method is required to make changes permanent and avoid any dialogs for saving changes made programmatically in Outlook.

When dealing with Exchange accounts in Outlook you may reach the limit of concurrently opened items if you iterate over all items in the folder/store. That is why `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods are recommended. They allow getting items that correspond to your search criteria and iterate over them only. Read more about these methods in the article that I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Comment: do you have a correspondent for it in powershell ?

Comment: The Outlook object model is common for all programming languages, so you may find what properties and methods should be used in articles.

Comment: For the `Unread` property, `Save` call is not required. Technically, read/unread status is not considered a message property per-se, and is stored separately.

Comment: Isn't it a bit flag MSGFLAG_READ in the message flags property? computed property?